# help on error org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Please help me get around this error . It comes sometimes at other times it does. I know its because of concurrent requests but how to overcome it ?? I tried lock instead of get but it did not work.

```
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect):
```

My code is :

```
def principal = springSecurityService.principal
    if (principal instanceof String)
        return null
    else {
        def user = NayaxUser.get(principal.id)
        user.merge()
        return user
    }
```

I have also tried using merge , but nothing seems to help.. Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

One thing I notice is that your code

```
user.merge()
return user
```

seems problematic, because as is specified in http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/merge.html:

> Unlike the save method this method returns a new instance of the class representing the re-attached object. [...] If you don't use the return value of the merge method then you still have access to the original detached instance and you will get errors such as lazy initialization exceptions.

So the correct code in your case would be

```
return user.merge()
```

However, I'm not sure whether this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input however the problem which i was facing was due to some other exception , that was that when any user used to click on something we wanted to store what he was doing .. In doing that we made a mistake by entering null value in a non nullable field which was associated with the User (in my code) , once we fixed that the above error was gone